# aptitude: How to search for nothing but the full name of a package?

Tags: search, aptitude

Searching for short package names (e.g. at or mc) in aptitude (not at command line but within the interactive tool) is annoying because I don't know a trick to avoid getting hits for plenty of packages that have these letters somewhere in their name when all I want to do is find at or mc themselves. (I have to jump through stuff like ttf-liber**at**ion or sw**at** and many more when all I want is **at** and nothing but **at**.)

There must be a trick to solve this annoying issue, because I can't be the first person who gets overwhelmed by the large number of results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To get information about the `at` package:

  ```
  aptitude show at
  ```
- To search for a literal `at`:

  ```
  aptitude search ^at$
  ```

  (`^` is a regular expression character that indicated a match from the beginning, `$` the end)

Comment: Awesome. The expression ^at$ in the second command you mention works also within the search field of aptitude's interactive tool. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. http://xkcd.com/208/ heh.

Comment: I've now one Ki reputation :D And regular expressions is one of the most useful inventions imo

Comment: Dank je wel voor de quick and good answer!